# How to generate good looking pie chart for large sets of data using Python?

Tags: python, pie-chart

I have two lists of data representing a float values and occurrence of corresponding values. When i generate the pie chart using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
pyplot.axis("equal")
pyplot.pie(count,labels=values,autopct="%1.1f%%")
pyplot.show()
```

where, the length of the lists count and values is 60, the labels gets overlapped and is not readable.If i reduce the size of the label using:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['font.size'] = 4.0
```

you have to zoom in quite a lot to read the values.

Is there any way to making it look readable without zooming in much and make it look pretty at the same time ?

Comment: not an answer but maybe 60 pie slices are too many for a figure...

Comment: Along the same lines of @joaquin's comment, if you read about data visualization you'll find an almost universal disdain for using pie charts as a bad way to present data. I would encourage you to consider alternatives, such as bar charts etc.

Comment: @joaquin you are right. I think making bar chart is more practical in this case.